# NHibernate Restrictions.Ge("ColumnName", DateTime.Now) produces invalid SQL

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a mapping like this for a DateTime column:

```
...
Map(x => x.Created).Column("CREATED")
                   .Access.Property()
                   .CustomType<DateTime>()
                   .CustomSqlType("datetime")
                   .Not.Nullable();
...
```

In my code I define

```
outboxCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Created", startDate));
```

where 'startDate' is of type DateTime.

When looking at the created SQL I see for the above criteria

```
...
    and Created = 2/14/2012 12:00:00 AM
...
```

which is not correct.  I would expect NHibernate to create

```
...
    and Created = '2/14/2012 12:00:00 AM'
...
```

I also observed that same problem with String types.

```
Map( x => x.ReceiverName).Column("UserName")
                         .CustomType("string")
                         .Access.Property()
                         .CustomSqlType("nvarchar(256)")
                         .Nullable()
                         .Length(256);
```

The resulting SQL does not put strings in quotes:

```
...
    and UserName = Paul
...
```

instead of

```
...
    and UserName = 'Paul'
...
```

The mapping works quite well except these problems.

What am I making wrong?

Comment: What happens if you drop the  `.CustomType<DateTime>()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specifying `.CustomSqlType("nvarchar(256)")` renders `Length()` to a noop. Also string and datetime are no customeTypes/customSqlTypes. Maybe NHibernate is confused by them.

Remove all but `Map( x => x.ReceiverName).Column("UserName").Length(256)`.